# Cannot find the page/object after click submit the form

Tags: php, mysql

I followed a online tutorial to connect my php code with MySQL. After I click the submit button, it said it cannot find the object (page). I did not see any code in my code? Any idea for me how to debug this code?

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'xxxxxx';
$db = 'testDB';
$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
echo"Great work!";

$id ="";
$fname="";
$midname="";
$lname="";



    function getPosts()
    {
        $posts =array();
        $posts[0]=$_POST['Contact_ID'];
        $posts[1]=$_POST['first_name'];
        $posts[2]=$_POST['middle_name'];
        $posts[3]=$_POST['last_name'];
        return $posts;

    }
    //search

    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $data = getPosts();

        $search_Query="select * from Contact where contact_ID =$data[0]";

        $search_Result=mysql_query($db, $search_Query);

        if($search_Result)
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($search_Result))
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($search_Result))
                {
                    $id =$row['contact_ID'];
                    $fname =$row['first_name'];
                    $midname =$row['middle_name'];
                    $lname =$row['last_name_name'];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo"No data for this Id";
            }

        }
        else
            echo"Result error";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE Html>  
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <form action="php_insert_update_delete_search.php" method="post">
        <input type="number", name="contact_ID" placeholder="Id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="text", name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="text", name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" value="<?php echo $midname;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="text", name="last_namename" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $lname;?>"><br><br>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
        </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure your action page is php_insert_update_delete_search.php?
Maybe there is typing mistake or you don't know what an action page does. You should also not name the action page so long

Comment: Is the php code and html  in the same page as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

remove `php_insert_update_delete_search.php` from the `action` of your `form`. The `form` is being redirected to `php_insert_update_delete_search.php` page when you click search button

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="contact_ID" placeholder="Id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" value="<?php echo $midname;?>"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_namename" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $lname;?>"><br><br>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

See You Have applied an action in your form tag . This action means that when ever a user will click on any button related to that form he or she will be redirected to that page (mentioned in action ) . So u need to make a page **php_insert_update_delete_search.php** and has to apply logic there for inserting the data .

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting the form to go to another page to run code to process what you need

```
<form action="pageyouneed.php" method="post">
```

if you want to use the current page to parse your code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; // Will return current document to parse code.
```